# Failed outbound s2s EXTERNAL authentication

Tags: ejabberd

I am trying to set up a locally-hosted ejabberd instance running in docker to use push notifications with monal-im.

I am getting the following error in the log

```
Failed outbound s2s EXTERNAL authentication chat.[MY DOMAIN].com -> eu.prod.push.monal-im.org (2.59.135.40): Authentication failed: Peer responded with error: unable to verify the first certificate (not-authorized)
```

I'm not an expert in security certificates, so I must be doing something quite wrong.

I have the following in my ejabberd.yml file:

```
 certfiles:
        
          - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/cert1.pem"

        ca_file: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/ejabberd.pem"
        
 listen
   -   
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
    certfile: "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/ejabberd.pem"
```

This resides in a docker container and port 80 is used by another container so I cannot forward it to this container, so I don't think I can use the acme service.  ejaabberd.pem is the private key, certificate, and chain combined.  The certificate CN is chat.[MY DOMAIN].com

Everything else seems to work.  I just can't get IOS users to get push notifications when their app is sleeping.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot?